# Using netdiscover with modified Screen View Parameter

Tags: linux, network-programming, ip, hosts, arp

So i have started using this awesome tool netdiscover.
I have been playing around with it for a while but I discovered something.

So there is this `Screen View` parameter, it has a value `Unique Hosts`.
What if I can change it to `Unique MAC Vendor / Hostname`  instead since that would save a lot of space with machine having different network interface and all.

I checked the manual for altering the parameter, googled but not much concrete is obtained till now

```
Currently scanning: 192.168.3.0/16   |   Screen View: Unique Hosts                                                                                                                                        

 0 Captured ARP Req/Rep packets, from 0 hosts.   Total size: 0                                                                                                                                             
 _____________________________________________________________________________
   IP            At MAC Address     Count     Len  MAC Vendor / Hostname      
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't change it to `Unique MAC Vendor / Hostname` in current netdiscover version.

There are only 4 screen view modes in netdiscover:

- "ARP Reply" mode, which show ARP replys list. The keyboard shortcut is `a`.
- "ARP Request" mode, which show ARP requests list. The keyboard shortcut is `r`.
- "Unique Hosts" mode, which show Unique Hosts detected. The keyboard shortcut is `u`.
- "Help" mode, which show help message. The keyboard shortcut is `h`.

You can check file `src/screen.c` in netdiscover's source code, and modify it if you want to implement this feature yourself.

Comment: Where is this source code located in git or somewhere else?
maybe I can contribute to the source code.

Comment: The Git repository of netdiscover can be found at https://github.com/alexxy/netdiscover